# What does it mean for a vector field to be perpendicular to a level surface?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

Assume I have a vector field expressed as:

$F=f(x,y,z)i + g(x,y,z)j +h(x,y,z)k$

Assume I have a level surface (spheres, ellipsoids, hyperboloid...) $S$.

What does it mean for $F$ to be perpendicular to $S$? In other words, what mathematical property must be satisfied?

Comment: If the level surface is given by $S: G(x,y,z) = C$ then $\nabla G$ is normal to $S$

Comment: You could find the normal vector to the surface and see if it is a multiple of F, or use the dot product between F and the surface normal to see if it is equal to the product of magnitudes (up to +/- sign).

Answer (score 2):

When we say some vector is perpendicular to some curve/surface at $p$, what we really mean is that vector is perpendicular to the tangent space of that curve/surface. In the case of the curve, the tangent space is a line. In the case of a surface, the tangent space is a plane.

In this case it means $F$ is perpendicular to the tangent plane of $S$ (at some point $p$). Which means that $F$ is orthogonal to all tangent vectors to $S$ at $p$.